# jquery if statement returns return worng statement

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm a bit new to Jquery and i run into  a problem...

in the following code - the if statement  doesn't suppose to go in the ELSE statement , because `$(this).css("color") ==="red") ...`

```
https://jsfiddle.net/roybarak/7mLsot7k/
```

What's worng with my code?

TNX , roy.

Comment: ["_Note that the computed style of an element may not be the same as the value specified for that element in a style sheet. For example, computed styles of dimensions are almost always pixels, but they can be specified as em, ex, px or % in a style sheet. Different browsers may return CSS color values that are logically but not textually equal, e.g., #FFF, #ffffff, and rgb(255,255,255)._"](http://api.jquery.com/css/)

Comment: console.log($(this).css("color"));

Comment: So what is the best method to chage CSS by if statements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick use of `console.log($(this).css("color"));` tells you that the color of the paragraph is "rgb(255, 0, 0)", at least according to Chrome.  As noted in the documentation cited below, different browsers may return colors in a different format.

I've modified the `if` statement to include what I believe to be the most common versions of "red":

```
$("p").click(function () {
    if ($(this).css("color").toLowerCase() == "rgb(255, 0, 0)" 
      || $(this).css("color").toLowerCase() == '#ff0000' 
      || $(this).css("color").toLowerCase() == '#f00') {
        alert("this is red");
    } else {
        alert("this is not red");
    }
});
```

Important section from [the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/css/), as pointed out by user Vohuman:

> "Note that the computed style of an element may not be the same as the
>   value specified for that element in a style sheet. For example,
>   computed styles of dimensions are almost always pixels, but they can
>   be specified as em, ex, px or % in a style sheet. Different browsers
>   may return CSS color values that are logically but not textually
>   equal, e.g., #FFF, #ffffff, and rgb(255,255,255)."

Demo:  https://jsfiddle.net/BenjaminRay/7mdxmhoy/

Comment: I have updated the code in my answer to be a bit more cross-browser friendly.  Not all browsers will return the color in the same way.